# Django 1.7.1 - keeps on using the dummy db engine

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I tried a thousand posts and nothing works for me on this...

- So I got my $DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE set to myproj.settings
- If I run python manage.py --setting=eventprowl.settings I get

> raise ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly
> configured. "    django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured:
> settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE
> value. Check settings documentation for more details.

- In my setting I have the following

> DATABASE_ENGINE   = 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'
>
> ```
> DATABASE_NAME     = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3')
> DATABASE_USER     = ''
> DATABASE_PASSWORD = ''
> DATABASE_HOST     = ''
> DATABASE_PORT     = ''
>
> DATABASES = {
>   'default': {
>     'ENGINE':   DATABASE_ENGINE,
>     'NAME':     DATABASE_NAME,
>     'USER':     DATABASE_USER,
>     'PASSWORD': DATABASE_PASSWORD,
>     'HOST':     DATABASE_HOST,
>     'PORT':     DATABASE_PORT,
>   }
> }
> ```

I tried uninstalling and installing again Django, but nothing changed. My folder structure is

```
myproj >
   manage.py
   myproj >
      settings.py
```

And I do not have any other settings files... But still, when I do

```
python manage.py diffsettings
```

I get the following for the databases:

> DATABASES = {'default': {'AUTOCOMMIT': True, 'ENGINE':
> 'django.db.backends.dummy', 'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False, 'NAME': '',
> 'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0, 'TIME_ZONE': 'UTC', 'PORT': '', 'HOST': '', 'USER':
> '', 'TEST': {'COLLATION': None, 'CHARSET': None, 'NAME': None,
> 'MIRROR': None}, 'PASSWORD': '', 'OPTIONS': {}}}

So the ENGINE is still django.db.backends.dummy...

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` looks wrong here. Should probably be `myproj.settings`. Start with the docs, maybe: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#envvar-DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE

Comment: @ThomasOrozco Awh, it was like that, I must have mistyped it, sorry. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

So I managed to fix it myself, the problem was that I had

```
DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()
```

This was there. because I am using Heroku, so I removed this line and it worked, now the final settings.py file looks like that:

```
import dj_database_url

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#databases

if DEBUG:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', 
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
            'USER': '',                      
            'PASSWORD': '',             
            'HOST': '',                     
            'PORT': '',                     
        }
        }
else:
    DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(default='postgres://localhost')}
```

You must remember to change the DEBUG variable value to False when you deploy.

Answer (score 0):

This will happen also with later versions. It happened with me for Django 2.2 
Basically it happens because `dj_database_url.config()` looks for `DATABASE_URL` and defaults to the dummy engine when the URL isn't found.